# How can I store the data of my Tkinter entries into a DataFrame to later export it to Excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I'm tryng to use a Tkinter window to ask for data entries, then take those entries, store the data into a Pandas DataFrame and later export the DataFrame to Excel. I want to store several rows of data from these user entries, and to save after each entry. Later I want to export the stored data. But my problem is I can't seem to get the data into a DataFrame. I've managed to export, an Excel file, but the only value it stored was Blank. Is there an easy way to get those values and insert them into a DataFrame? I'm familiar with Pandas and know how to export, but I'm fairly new to Tkinter.

I have tried inserting data with insert() to the DataFrame, I've tried using entry.get() to store the values and pass them to the DataFrame, but none of those worked. I've now tried to use get() for the values, store them into a list and then turn that list into a DataFrame, but the values just won't go into the DataFrame. I haven't tried openpyxl because the examples I have read don't seem to work for what I have in mind, meaning that I could manage to export a file with the example data but not for the actual purpose of my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def saveinfo():
    valor = entry1.get()
    list.append(valor)

def export():
    df = pd.DataFrame(list)
    df.to_excel("DataBase.xlsx")

def opennewwindow():
    window.destroy()
    newwindow=tk.Tk()
    newwindow.geometry("500x150")
    newwindow.title("Hi! ")
    titulo = tk.Label(newwindow, text = "Please, enter data: ", font=("Calibri", 10)).grid(column = 0, row = 0)
    textoentry1 = tk.Label(newwindow, text = "Number", font = ("Arial", 8)).grid(column = 0, row = 1)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(newwindow, width=10).grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    textoentry2 = tk.Label(newwindow, text = "Description", font = ("Arial", 8)).grid(column = 0, row = 2)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(newwindow, width=10).grid(column = 1, row = 2)
    textoentry3 = tk.Label(newwindow, text = "Brand", font = ("Arial", 8)).grid(column = 0, row = 3)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(newwindow, width=10).grid(column = 1, row = 3)
    botonguardar = tk.Button(newwindow, text = "Save", command = saveinfo).grid(column = 3, row = 2)
    botonexportar = tk.Button(newwindow, text = "Export", command = export).grid(column = 3, row = 3)
    newwindow.mainloop()


df = pd.DataFrame
list = []

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("320x156")
window.title("Master")
label = tk.Label(window, text = "Platform", font = ("Arial", 25)).grid(column = 0, row = 0)
boton = tk.Button(window, text = "Choose an element: ", command = opennewwindow)
boton.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

window.mainloop()
```

I expect to receive an exported Excel file that shows a DataFrame with the values that were written in the Entry boxes. For Example: there are 3 entries and I want an Excel with several rows that show those 3 entries in 3 columns: "Number", "Description" and "Brand". Instead, I get a Blank Excel.

I know that my code is not clean yet, I haven't refactored or tidied up since I'm tryng to get a functional MVP for my idea. Thanks for any feedback or ideas!

Comment: It should not be related to your error, but `list` is a built-in function in python. Do not use it as a variable.

Comment: By the way, you should make a class to represent your gui. It will make all things easier.

Comment: Completely true for both of your comments, tbh I was coding in a rush but I should always follow the basics. Thanks for pointing those out, I will fix it once I refactor. Could you shed some light about my Entry Data Storage problem?

Comment: If I test your code, I get `NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined` when I press the save button. You define the `entry1` Entry widget in `openwindow` function. So it is not in `saveinfo()` namespace. However you didn't report for this error, hence I've no idea about what is really going on in your code. Are you sure you posted all the code you are running?

Comment: Hi! That's exactly the Issue I'm trying to solve! See, between the Save and Export buttons I should get the functionality of saving the entries to a DataFrame ("Save") and exporting that DataFrame to an Excel file ("Export"). entry1 is not defined in the saveinfo() namespace because I was trying to see if I could call it directly, I tried passing it as an argument earlier but to no avail. That error represents all the functionality I'm lacking and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: `entry1` is local variable which exists only in `opennewwindow`. You should use `global entry1` in `opennewwindow` to inform this function that it has to use external/global variable when you do `entry1 = ...`

Second: using `entry1 = tk.Entry(...).grid(...)` you assign `None` to `entry1` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` always return `None`. You have to do it in two steps:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry(...)
entry1.grid(...)
```

---

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def saveinfo():
    valor1 = entry1.get()
    valor2 = entry2.get()
    valor3 = entry3.get()

    data.append([valor1, valor2, valor3])
    print(data)

def export():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel("DataBase.xlsx")

def opennewwindow():
    global entry1
    global entry2
    global entry3

    window.destroy()

    newwindow = tk.Tk()

    tk.Label(newwindow, text="Please, enter data: ").grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

    tk.Label(newwindow, text="Number").grid(column=0, row=1)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(newwindow)
    entry1.grid(column=1, row=1)

    tk.Label(newwindow, text="Description", ).grid(column=0, row=2)
    entry2 = tk.Entry(newwindow)
    entry2.grid(column=1, row=2)

    tk.Label(newwindow, text="Brand").grid(column=0, row=3)
    entry3 = tk.Entry(newwindow)
    entry3.grid(column=1, row=3)

    tk.Button(newwindow, text="Save", command=saveinfo).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky='we')
    tk.Button(newwindow, text="Export", command=export).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='we')

    newwindow.mainloop()

# --- main ---

df = pd.DataFrame
data = []

window = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(window, text="Platform").grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Button(window, text="Choose an element: ", command=opennewwindow).grid(column=0, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you so much for your help, I learned a lot and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you how to do it with OOP and classes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.geometry("320x156")
        self.title("Master")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text = "Platform", font = ("Arial", 25))
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.boton = tk.Button(self, text = "Choose an element: ", command = self.opendialog)
        self.boton.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

    def opendialog(self):
        dial = Dialog()

class Dialog(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__()
        self.titulo = tk.Label(self, text = "Please, enter data: ", font=("Calibri", 10))
        self.titulo.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        self.textoentry1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Number", font = ("Arial", 8))
        self.textoentry1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        self.textoentry2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Description", font = ("Arial", 8))
        self.textoentry2.grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry2.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.textoentry3 = tk.Label(self, text = "Brand", font = ("Arial", 8))
        self.textoentry3.grid(column = 0, row = 3)
        self.entry3 = tk.Entry(self, width=10)
        self.entry3.grid(column = 1, row = 3)
        self.botonguardar = tk.Button(self, text = "Save", command = self.saveinfo)
        self.botonguardar.grid(column = 3, row = 2)
        self.botonexportar = tk.Button(self, text = "Export", command = self.export)
        self.botonexportar.grid(column = 3, row = 3)
        self.data = []

    def saveinfo(self):
        valor = self.entry1.get()
        self.data.append(valor)

    def export(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(self.data)
        df.to_excel("DataBase.xlsx")

window = App()
window.mainloop()
```

As you see, each window is a class. The elements (widgets) of the window are attributes of the class, defined in the `__init__` method. Also the `data` list where you want to store the values is an attribute of the class.
Other methods of the class are used as callbacks, and have naturally access to the attributes.

The only difference with your code, is that here I do not destroy the main window when the dialog is shown.